# Convert any video to DVD in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, video, media-converter

Actually, I'm looking for alternatives for [ConvertXToDVD](http://www.vso-software.fr/products/convert_x_to_dvd/) that works on Ubuntu.

**Requirements:**

- Convert various video formats (.avi,.mp4...) to a format that's readable on a DVD player;
- Add subtitles and change the text format (font,color,screen position) for them;
- Customize chapters;
- Create menus with custom options and background sound;
- Burn the DVD and/or create the ISO file is a plus, but not mandatory to me;
- Free and Open Source is a plus also;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a good software to do these things in Ubuntu. It's [DeVeDe](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/devede/)

From what I could test until now, it is far away from the possibilities of ConvertXToDVD, but it's a very good option to make DVDs in Ubuntu.

**Requirements that match** (from my tests until now)**:**

- Convert various video formats (.avi,.mp4...) to a format that's readable on a DVD player;
- Add subtitles and change the text format (font,color,screen position) for them;
- Create menus with custom options and background sound;
- Free and Open Source;